# Simple seaborn distribution plot not working

Tags: python, plot, statistics, seaborn, distribution

I’m trying to plot the distribution of scores on reddit posts, but can’t figure it out.

My data frame is something like that

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"score": [12, 19, 25987, 887, 887, 1],
                  "author": ["xxx", "x", "xxx", "xx", "xxxx", "x"]})
```

With a lot more data points (about 300,000).

I have attempted the following two things:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.displot(data=df, x="score", bins=30, kde=True)
plt.title('Distribution of Post Scores')
plt.xlabel('Score')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')

plt.show()
```

But it gives me the following:

[image]

And I’ve tried this:

```
score_freq = df['score'].value_counts()

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.displot(score_freq, kind="kde", bw_adjust=30)
plt.title('Distribution of Post Scores')
plt.xlabel('Score')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')

plt.show()
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

So the second option seems a bit better, though still wrong. I don’t have scores that go all the way to -100,000, and I **do** have scores that go all the way to 299,489.

I don’t really get what I’m doing wrong.

### Update

This is what the real data looks like when I do `df['score'].sort_values()`:

[image]

And this is what it looks like with `df['score'].value_counts()`:
[image]

Comment: `sns.displot(data=df, x="score", bins=30, kde=True)` works fine…

Comment: You need to rethink what you are trying to achieve with this. A distribution plot is an univariable plot which shows the frequency of the variable you are displaying. Also the first dataframe construction is not propperly done, since you are passing 2 dictionaries, it should be onle 1 dictionary with 2 keys: `df = pd.DataFrame({"score": [12, 19, 25987, 887, 887, 1], "author": ["xxx", "x", "xxx", "xx", "xxxx", "x"]})`

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the data frame construction. That, however, does not influence the results, because I just made it by hand for the example. With respect to the distribution plot, that is exactly what I want to achieve: an univariable plot which shows the frequency of the variable, which here is the score. So what do I need to rethink? Am I not giving it a unique variable (i.e. the score)?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"score": [12, 19, 25987, 887, 887, 1],
                   "author": ["xxx", "x", "xxx", "xx", "xxxx", "x"]})

# Plotting using seaborn's displot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.histplot(data=df, x="score", bins=30, kde=True)
plt.title('Distribution of Post Scores')
plt.xlabel('Score')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')

plt.show()
```

[image: output]

Comment: This is exactly the same as OP's `sns.displot(data=df, x="score", bins=30, kde=True)` (which works fine).

Comment: When I do that I get the same graph as figure 1 in my question. I guess it really comes from my data in the data frame then. I updated my question to part of the real data.